# Generic columns array shows any in callback value

Tags: typescript

I have this code to type columns automatically, so I won't have to specify it any time, but it has one problem with `array[]` keys.

When highlighting the `render` key it seems to show the right type, but the real `callback (value) => value.id` seems to have an `any` type.

```
type Payload = {
  name: string;
  items: string[];
};

type Render<P> = (value: P) => any;

type Col<
  T extends object,
  K = keyof T | Array<keyof T>
> = K extends Array<keyof T>
  ? {
      key: K;
      render: Render<{ [key in K[number]]: T[key] }>
    }
  : K extends keyof T ? {
      key: K;
      render: Render<T[K]>
    } : never


const cols: Col<Payload>[] = [
  { 
    key: 'name', 
    render: (name) => name 
  },
  { 
    key: ['name', 'items'],
    render: (obj) => `${obj.name} - ${obj.items.length}`
  },
];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiANgezgEygXigbwLABQUUAdnALYQBcUAzsAE4CWJA5gNyHFPATm016zNgG0AupwIBfSYVCQoAJQgk0EBgB4YAPixQAFADc4iAK7VYASiy64JELILzoAYWSINXKABUoEAB68qrRQyABGAFYQAMbAADReANJ6ANYQIMgAZj5QAD5QAIIMDAgaaRnZ3tqEutjJAUFoIUUlIGXpWT7VRFAA-LhexMTlNImSQ0MMKmoMNMqq6ho4UCLlUCxQiSIkpuRh6mJiNN6r6WJQUt0TUl6jfoHTIeWdvv34PRMjm%20MTUFMLsyU00WJ0SYiuQykUBoJAghnUhERBGiyBI9CgKMQAigbg88CQqDQ2nEehEXmWgygXwA5GRKNS4lBKf8ZjR9HSINZMLoOUyelIEj0KR8qekaCJaRQIAyoNSeHxaNSxIKJiz1GzwhEuboAAYAEhwmoAdByoQBaKAG43y-hGxAqVjAAAWUh1XgFhAkQA)

Answer (score -1):

There isn't information to infer the type of `obj` on this line, it is being inferred as `any`:

```js
  render: (obj) => `${obj.name} - ${obj.items.length}`
```

Adding a type annotation gets rid if the `any`:

```js
  render: (obj: Payload) => `${obj.name} - ${obj.items.length}`
```

Comment: would love if `type Col` type could take care of that as in all other cases it does but only if an array key it doesn't